Plotly.js Boxplot first one is always red
I'm unable to figure out why but the first boxplot is always red and doesn't follow the marker color. Any idea why this would be?
const layout = {
  "font": {
    "color": "darkgrey"
  },
  "hovermode": "closest",
  "margin": {
    "b": 20,
    "t": 30
  },
  "paper_bgcolor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
  "plot_bgcolor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
  "xaxis": {
    "autorange": true,
    "range": [
      -0.5,
      6.5
    ],
    "type": "category"
  }
}

const data = [{name: 'name', maker:{color:'#1f77b4}, type:'box', boxpoints:'all', pointpos:0, y:[array of points]}, ...]


